# Pop up problem when scraping Androidy Store BeautifulSoup / Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, google-play

[image]I have a problem to detect a button with Selenium when a confirmation window pops-up. I'm scraping the android store to automate an app downloading everything works but when I have to confirm by clicking the Install button I can't do the same code that I used to just before.

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()

driver.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details? 
id=com.king.candycrushsaga")

connexionbutton= "//*[@id='gb_70']"
emailfield= "identifierId"
GoogleAccUser="****@gmail.com"
GoogleAccPassword="****"
passwordfield="//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input"
nextButton = "//*[@id='identifierNext']/content/span"
nextButtonTwo = "//*[@id='passwordNext']/content/span"
appsTabW  = "//* . 
[@id='wrapper']/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/a/span/span[2]"
appsTab = "//*[@id='wrapper']/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/a"
installButton = "//*[@id='fcxH9b']/div[4]/c- 
wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/c-wiz[1]/c- 
wiz[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/c- 
wiz/div/span/button"
confirmInstallButton = "//*[@id='purchase-ok-button']/span"
 xx = "//*[@id='purchase-ok-button']/span"
 #listderoulante = "//*[@id='device-selector-container']/div/button/div[1]"



loginbuttonElement = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda 
driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathbutton))
loginbuttonElement.click()

emailFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda 
driver: driver.find_element_by_id(emailfield))
 emailFieldElement.clear()
emailFieldElement.send_keys(GoogleAccUser)

nextButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda 
driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(nextButton))
nextButtonElement.click()

passwordFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda 
driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(passwordfield))
passwordFieldElement.clear()
passwordFieldElement.send_keys(GoogleAccPassword)

nextButtonElementTwo = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda 
driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(nextButtonTwo))
nextButtonElementTwo.click()

installButtonElement = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda 
driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(installButton))
installButtonElement.click()
#print(installButtonElement)

#print (confirmInstallButtonElement)
```

Is there a way to handle pop-up windows or this problem with Selenium? Thank you